# Div does not allow scroll despite adding scroll to style

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a modal in my render method:

```
  <ModalContainer>
    <Modal isSmall={true} style={{width:'1100px', overflowY : "scroll"}}>
        <div className='div-style'>
      <ModalHeader>
        <h3>Add Company</h3>
      </ModalHeader>
      <div className='div-style'>
      {addingC.map((company, index) => { //renders each element in addingC, I want this div to be scroll-able as the user keeps adding a new object
          return(
            <div
            key={index}
            className="flex flex-row w-100 side-by-side"
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "row",
              justifyContent: "space-between",
              marginBottom: "20px",
            }}
          >
        <label htmlFor="name">Company Name</label>
        <ModalInput
          type="text"
          id="name"
          value={company.name}
          onChange={(e) =>
            this.setState({ newCompanyName: e.target.value })
          }
        ></ModalInput>
        <label htmlFor="website">
        Company Website
        </label>
        <ModalInput
          type="text"
          id="website"
          value={company.website}
          onChange={(e) =>
            this.setState({ newCompanyWebsite: e.target.value })
          }
        ></ModalInput>
      </div>


        )})}
          </div>
            <ModalSaveButton type="button" onClick={() => this.addC()}> //add button that allows user to add another company
            add
              </ModalSaveButton>
```

this is the `addC()` method and adds in an empty object when called by the render method:

```
  addC() {
    let { addingC } = this.state;
    addingC.push({ name: "", website: ""});

    this.setState({ addingC });
  }
```

this is the css file where I have also added Y overflow property:

```
.side-by-side {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
.div-style {
  overflow-y: auto; //added Y overflow
  position: relative;
}
```

I would like the div to be scroll-able as the user adds new companies and currently once I add about 8 companies, the div becomes too large and instead of scrolling, the top part goes out of the page so its no longer visible [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR297.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use overflow-y or overflow-x, you have to set height or width. Otherwise, it will keep using available space. If there is no space, it will go off the page. 
In your CSS file, try adding height in div-style.